Microtype confusion with both tracking and ligatures
I find section 5.3 of Microtype's documentation (v3.1b) confusing: about the no ligatures option, it starts by saying that "by default, ligatures in letterspaced fonts will be constructed as usual". But later on, it says "The default settings disable ligatures for the character ‘f’ only", and indeed that seems to be the case.
I'd like to restore the f ligatures by default, but I can't find a simple way to do so. One trick is to call \SetTracking with no ligatures=X, so that only (inexistent) ligatures starting with an X would be disabled. But this is not very satisfactory.
An I missing something?
Thanks!

Please provide a minimal working example and specify the engine you're using.

re confusing: indeed! "by default" means: if settings wouldn't exist at all, but then "default settings" do exist (in microtype.cfg). I'll reword this. As for restoring the f ligatures, for the time being the X hack is the only possibility, the next version (dev on github) will allow the option no ligatures=none (a confusing double negative... ;-).

Excellent. Thank you!
